# CefSharp WPF Crash

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I try to use CefSharp with WPF. In the developer machine works as expected, but in othes pc, I receive this error:

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated
>   due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException at
>   CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.Dispose(Boolean) at
>   CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.Finalize()

I install vc++ redist 2013(x86 or x64) on the target computer, but not work. I also try this: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies, but nothing works.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe your application is using latest version of CefSharp. 
Latest CEFSharp version depends on VC++ 2015.

What is the build platform of your application ?

- If it is x86, then install vc++ 2015 (x86)
- If it is x64, then install vc++ 2015 (x64)

You can also choose to install vc++ 2017 redistributable, as it also works with latest CEFSharp.

This should surely resolve your issue.

Comment: Optionally you can place the binaries `msvcp140.dll` and `vcruntime140.dll` in the directory with your application - it will also solve the issue. If the system still complains about missing system DLLs, install `KB2999226`